# how to manually install SQLite in Azure Web App (windows environment, PHP language)

Tags: sqlite, azure-web-app-service

I am following this tutorial(https://cgillum.tech/2016/06/30/creating-a-corporate-wiki-in-azure/) to setup Mediawiki which need to install SQLite in Azure Web App. But the tutorial did not mention how to setup SQLite in Azure Web App.

When I go to Mediawiki Configuration page. It does not find SQLite.
I tried to follow the link https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php to install but I don't find any php.info in Azure Web App.

(Environment for Azure Web App: windows enviornment, PHP language)

Comment: You can check this post. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/42bf076d-883e-4818-8585-7bfedff1ff5c/how-to-enable-sqlite3-for-php-in-azure-websites?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Comment: Do you have any concerns about this issue?

Comment: Hi @JasonPan, thanks for your response. I didn't try this method because the answer seems a little vague and general to me. I was looking for a more detailed tutorials for steps on how to install/use SQLite on Azure Web App

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the `php_sqlite3.dll` for the correct PHP version. Upload the file and add the following environment variable for the website in app settings.

[image]

For more details, you can refer to below links.

[1. Enable PHP extensions on Azure Web App on Windows](https://azureossd.github.io/2017/08/21/enable-php-extensions-on-azure-web-app-on-windows/)

[2. Adding SQLite3 extension to a PHP Web App](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8aad8e33-191d-4580-8558-79427414a30c/adding-sqlite3-extension-to-a-php-web-app?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview)

[3. How to enable SQLite3 for PHP in Azure Websites?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/42bf076d-883e-4818-8585-7bfedff1ff5c/how-to-enable-sqlite3-for-php-in-azure-websites?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview)

[4. Enable PHP SQLite3 database extension for Azure Web App](https://maktel.github.io/blog/2017/08/20/php-enable-sqlite3-extension-for-azure-web-app)